# Color Picker for Windows store App

Tags: vb.net, windows-store-apps, color-picker, colordialog

I want to add a color picker control to a windows store App (using VB), I came to know that there is no standard control for that. So any ideas about what could be a good purchased or open source option?

Answer (score 0):

So I started building one into WinRT XAML Toolkit [here](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.xaml) but never got round to finishing it. Mainly because I figured there would need to be very different designs for different platforms. The control isn't finished, but a lot of the components that are there you could use to build a color picker that fits your design. There's a [`ColorExtensions`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/ColorExtensions.cs) class that might help you convert between HSL/HSV/RGB models, there's a `FromString()` method in it that can parse a color string in the formats available in XAML (e.g. "Transparent" or #FFAA0080 or #FB0) and there's a [`WriteableBitmapColorPickerExtensions`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapColorPickerExtensions.cs) class that you can use to render a hue ring, 2D color selector bitmap or a 1D color bar. I'll probably create some usable controls one day to use all of these primitives, but for now - you have that power! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I've created a simple color picker for Universal Apps, you can read about it from this [blog post](http://www.tareqateik.com/colorpicker-control-for-universal-apps)...